# I can not execute .bin file in a external usb

Tags: command-line, usb, permissions

One moth ago I install cmap tools in my home folder, but now I want to install cmap in my external usb.

I always install cmap.bin in my home folder using this command:

```
chmod +x file-cmap.bin
```

but now when I try it in a external usb it says me this:

```
chmod: cannot access 'cmap.bin': No such file or directory
```

I try to pointed to the folder typing:

```
sudo chmod +x /media/xavi/Elements/ubuntu_programes/cmap.bin
```

but it does not work.

please help, and thanks for the time.

Comment: did you pointed or `cd` where file-cmap.bin is? `sudo chmod +x /path/to/the/file`

Comment: yes I do it, but another time: chmod: cannot access /media/xalsar/Elements/ubuntu_programes/cmap.bin': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

As the error states there is no `cmap.bin` in `/media/xavi/Elements/ubuntu_programes/`.

Check if the file has the right name:
Change to the directory with `cd /media/xavi/Elements/ubuntu_programes/` and list the files with `ls -la`

If the file has the wrong name change it with:
`mv wrongFileName cmap.bin`

If it does not exist at all copy it there with:
 `cp /path/to/loca/cmap.bin /media/xavi/Elements/ubuntu_programes/cmap.bin`

Comment: again :No such file or directory

Comment: At which step did of my answer did you get the error?

Comment: at: mv wrongFileName cmap.bin

Comment: Was the file `cmap.bin` there but just with a wrong name? If so you have to replace `wrongFIleName` with the name the file has. If there is no file you cant move it.

Comment: I try it but it say's my: mv: missing destination file operand after 'cmap.bin'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: You should read the mv manpage: `man mv`. `mv` moves a file to another location. In this case used to rename the file if it had a wrong name. If there is no file, copy it with `cp` as I suggested in my answer. Don't forget to replace `/path/to/loca/cmap.bin` with the actual path.

Comment: It can be a problem that the file does not have permissions ?

Comment: No then the error would be `Permission denied`. There is no file `/media/xavi/Elements/ubuntu_programes/cmap.bin`. Just copy it there.

Comment: But what I have to do with mv manpage ? I read it but I do not understand what I have to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23506/discussion-between-pabi-and-xalsar).